# How to extract href from String and make it clickable

Tags: android, href

I'm getting a html string and I want to extract the href string from them and make only those values clickable to start some custom activity before setting them in a TextView. I have tried this

```
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(textPost.getDescription());
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
for(URLSpan span : urls) {
       int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
       int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
       int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
       ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
               public void onClick(View view) {
                     Log.d("Home Activity", "Clicked yay");         
               }
        };
        strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
        strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}
textHolder.content.setText(strBuilder);
```

This is highlighting the text but when I click on them the log message isn't getting print

Comment: What do you actually want like:- a link in the texview which is clickable or emaoil id in the text view which is also clikable??

Comment: A link in that text view that is clickable. I have a html string which looks something like this "<span=\"@someone\" class=\"atwho-inserted\"><a data-tagged=\"true\" href=\"/random-link\">Clickable Part</a></span>‍ This is another random text." I just want to make the "Clickable Part" as clickable

Comment: Yours textview's data is fixed or dynamic??

Comment: It's dynamic. And the number of hrefs I get will also vary

Comment: And you want to open another activity on click on textview's link??Not browser or Gmail , you want to open??

Comment: Yes, I want to open another activity on textview's click.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the hyperlink from string

```
Pattern.compile("[a-z]+:\/\/[^ \n]*").matcher(
"download_recording true Package available http://ab.com click the link").find();
```

and to make it click-able

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHolder);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.sampleText)));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: On the click I want it to launch a custom activity not launch the browser.

Comment: @ShashankUdupa .. Is your click event on textview is number or text or hyperlink??

Comment: After an api call I get a html string like String response = "<span><a href="/something">Clickable text</a></span> Random stuff". I need to set this string in a TextView such that it comes as "Clickable text Random stuff" where when "Clickable text" is clicked, a new activity starts.

Comment: @ShashankUdupa, my first pattern string will give you the specific string. set it to textview or anyother widget and start activity